# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 Express Edition (64-bit) RTM Product Level.

I am not able to see SQL Server Agent After installing the setup. I tried through Services as well, but it gives an error. Does Express edition not have SQL Server Agent included?

If not which Edition should I download?

Comment: The Express editions don't have the SQL Server Agent ....

Comment: As Marc mentioned ,Express editions doesn't have SQLServer agent.`If not which Edition should i download?`.standard/Enterprise have SQLServer agent

Comment: if this is for learning purpose,you can download developed edition as well

Comment: Thank You So Much for the answers.
Can someone provide me the link for downloading Standard/Enterprise SSMS?